# Find and convert scripture reference to wiki link

Tags: python, string, for-loop, url-rewriting, find

I use a Bible inside of Obsidian that works fine when linking to one verse at a time. However, I still need to be able to link to ranges of verses. I decided to try to write a Python script that finds scripture references, and when it sees a "-" or "+" it writes out every verse of said range as it’s own link.

Example:
An Obsidian file (let’s say `Scripture reference test.md`) would have text in it like: `“In [[Gen 1:1-4]], we can draw out fundamental principles which can also be seen in the great battle between Christ and Satan, as well as the salvation of man. See more at [[The Great Controversy]].”` The string “Gen” is a part of a list which the script recognizes and acts upon, whereas “[[The Great Controversy]]” is not. The script makes a new file with the name of the reference (`Gen 1:1-4`) - which correlates to the link in `Scripture reference test.md` . Then, it takes the verse range `1-4` and prints out an appropriate list of embed links to that new file (represented by `rtemp.md` in the script) so that, all scriptures in the given range are seen when the link is previewed in Obsidian. This method also doesn’t touch the notes containing the actual scriptures being linked to.

```
![[Gen 1#1|Gen 1:1]]
![[Gen 1#2|Gen 1:2]]
![[Gen 1#3|Gen 1:3]]
![[Gen 1#4|Gen 1:4]]
```

Example 2: "Gen 1:1-2+5" would generate:

```
![[Gen 1#1|Gen 1:1]]
![[Gen 1#2|Gen 1:2]]
![[Gen 1#5|Gen 1:5]]
```

In the new file.

I’m new to Python (teaching myself in my spare time). Besides my code not doing anything (no errors, prints, or writing), I’m sure there is a more efficient way to go about writing this script. What am I missing or doing wrong?

```
import os
import re
from itertools import groupby

efile = "Scripture reference test.md"

tfile = "srtemp.md"

dirName = '/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~md~obsidian/Documents/Obsidian-vault/The Bible (KJV)';

chRefs = ["Gen ", "Exod ", "Lev ", "Num ", "Deut ", "Josh ", "Judg ", "Ruth ", "1Sam ", "2Sam ", "1Kings ", "2Kings ", "1Chron ", "2Chron ", "Ezr ", "Neh ", "Esth ", "Job ", "Ps ", "Prov ", "Eccless ", "Song ", "Isa ", "Jer ", "Lam ", "Ezek ", "Dan ", "Hos ", "Joel ", "Amos ", "Obad ", "Jonah ", "Micah ", "Nah ", "Hab ", "Zeph ", "Hag ", "Zech ", "Mal ", "Matt ", "Mark ", "Luke ", "John ", "Acts ", "Rom ", "1Cor ", "2Cor ", "Gal ", "Ephes ", "Phil ", "Col ", "1Thess ", "2Thess ", "1Tim ", "2Tim ", "Phil ", "Heb ", "James ", "1Pet ", "2Pet ", "1John ", "2John ", "3John ", "Jude ", "Rev "]
#for chRef in chRefs:
    #pass

#check for referrences:
def rangeInt():
    with open(tfile, 'w') as wf:
        with open(efile, 'r+') as ef:
            efl = ef.readlines()
            for line in efl:
                if any(chRef in line for chRef in chRefs):
                    m = re.search('\[\[(.+?)]]', line)
                    if m:
                        foundRef = m.group(1) + "\n"

                        ref = foundRef.split(' ')
                        book = ref[0]
                        rnumsL1 = ref[1]
                        rnumsL1.split(':')
                        chapter = rnumsL1[0]
                        rnumsL2 = rnumsL1[1]
                        if '-' in rnumsL2:
                            if rnumsL2.find('-') < rnumsL2.find('+'):
                                rnumsL2.split('-',1)
                                firstVerse = rnumsL2[0]
                                ad1 = rnumsL2[1]
                                if '+' in rnumsL2:
                                    ad1.split('+',1)
                                    aP1 = ad1[1]
                                    if '-' in aP1:
                                        aP1.split('-',1)
                                        ad2 = aP1[1]
                                        sfv = aP1[0]
                                    else:
                                        lastVerse = aP1
                                else: lastVerse = ad1

                            elif rnumsL2.find('-') > rnumsL2.find('+') or '+' in rnumsL2 and '-' not in rnumsL2:
                                #check this area if problem:
                                ad1.split('+',1)
                                secfv = ad1[1]
                                if '-' in rnumsL3:
                                    ad1.split('-',1)
                                    aP1 = rnumsL3[1]
                                else:
                                    lastVerse = ad1[1]
                            else: lastVerse = rnumsL2[1]
                        else:
                            lastVerse = rnumsL2[0]

                def rangeConv():
                    if book != '' and chapter != '' and lastVerse > rnumsL2:
                        if rnumsL2[1] != '':
                            for n in foundRef:
                                if n < lastVerse:
                                    print('![[' + book + ' ' + chapter + '#' + n + '|' + book + ' ' + chapter + ':' + n + ']]\n')

                                    wf.write('[[' + book + ' ' + chapter + '#' + n + '|' + book + ' ' + chapter + ':' + n + ']]\n')
                        else:
                            print('only one verse given')
                rangeConv()

rangeInt()
```

Also, instead of only being able to handle a scripture reference with up to 2 "-", or 2 "+", I would prefer the scripture to be able to recognize and write verses for an unlimited amount of "-" and "+".

Comment: You need to supply sample input and expected output in your question.

Comment: Are you looking to create a file that *only* contains the references, i.e. you're not trying to replace the text references, or turn them into links? It would be very helpful if you provided an example source text (brief) and the result you would expect for that source text (as @martineau is indicating)

Comment: Also, does the pattern `Book c:v` or `Book c:va-vb` or `Book c:va-vb+vc` cover all possibilities? What about other common formats like `Book ca:va-vb, cb:vc-vd` or perhaps `Book c:va-vb+vc-vd`? And will the references always have no whitespace inbetween the referred verses and symbols?

Comment: @Grismar Yes I am looking to make a file only containing the reference links. And I did add 2 examples above. Here they are again: Example: "Gen 1:1-3" would be:

[[Gen 1#1]]
[[Gen 1#2]]
[[Gen 1#3]]
Example 2: "Gen 1:1-3+5" would be:

[[Gen 1#1]]
[[Gen 1#2]]
[[Gen 1#3]]
[[Gen 1#5]]

Comment: @Grismar Yah I was thinking about that… it doesn’t cover all possibilities and can’t take in a very long reference right now… is there any approach other then making a lot of nested of statements to handle all possibilities? - something that could potentially handle an indefinitely long reference (containing “-“ and “+”)?

Comment: The examples you provided were clear, however what we mean is to provide an example of what a file like `Scripture reference test.md` would look like (just a short sample, a few lines) and what the corresponding `rtemp.md` would have to look like. Once you have a file with a list of links (and only links), what is your next step? What good will the list of links be outside a text?

Comment: @Grismar ohh ok. Sorry for the misunderstanding. The `Scripture reference test.md` File represents a note page in Obsidian. An example can be: `[[Gen 1:1-5]] shows the first day of creation. Learn more about the symbolic significances [[here]]. ` The `rtemp.md` file represents a new obsidian file made to hold embeds to each scripture in the range. Example: `[[Gen 1#1]]
[[Gen 1#2]]
[[Gen 1#3]] [[Gen 1#4]]
[[Gen 1#5]]` . Since Obsidian can preview links, this new file will show all the verses in my note (like `Scripture reference test.md`) Without altering the actual scriptures

Comment: Please update your question when people ask for more detail, don't put relevant data or code in the comments. So, you're saying that in the source file you are scanning, the references will already be links of the form `[[Gen 1:1-5]]` (or similar, as described)? If that's the case, a regular expression using the fact that they have brackets would make the job fairly straightforward - just confirming that's what you're doing.

Comment: @Grismar oh sorry. I’m fairly new to  this site. That makes sense. And yes! They will already be in that format. What do you mean by a regular expression?

Comment: Have a look below - don't be intimidated by the complexity of the regex needed here - I linked a site that you can play around with to get a sense of the power of them.

Comment: @Grismar oh my goodness. Thank you so much! I knew I wasn’t approaching it the best way and the way you did it (while a lot of things are new to me) makes a lot of sense!! I really appreciate how you broke it down and explained the things you did, the site, and even the rules (which help me get a clearer picture). Also, these things help me to understand more about Python as well as the kind of mindset needed as a developer. So Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome - feel free to accept the answer if it meets your needs, by clicking the checkmark next to it. If you have further questions about the answer, consider asking for clarification in its comments. If it raises new questions, maybe just ask a whole new question on SO.

Comment: @Grismar ah ok. Will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input files look like this:

```
[[Gen 1:1-5]] shows the first day of creation. Learn more about the symbolic significances [[here]].
Or have a quick read of [[Mark 5:6-13+16]] for something completely different.
```

And you're looking for output like this:

```
[[Gen 1:1]]
..             (continued, .. for brevity)
[[Gen 1:5]]
[[Mark 5:6]]
..
[[Mark 5:13]]
[[Mark 5:16]]
```

Then your script could be as simple as:

```
import re

ch_refs = ["Gen ", "Exod ", "Lev ", "Num ", "Deut ", "Josh ", "Judg ", "Ruth ", "1Sam ", "2Sam ", "1Kings ", "2Kings ", "1Chron ", "2Chron ", "Ezr ", "Neh ", "Esth ", "Job ", "Ps ", "Prov ", "Eccless ", "Song ", "Isa ", "Jer ", "Lam ", "Ezek ", "Dan ", "Hos ", "Joel ", "Amos ", "Obad ", "Jonah ", "Micah ", "Nah ", "Hab ", "Zeph ", "Hag ", "Zech ", "Mal ", "Matt ", "Mark ", "Luke ", "John ", "Acts ", "Rom ", "1Cor ", "2Cor ", "Gal ", "Ephes ", "Phil ", "Col ", "1Thess ", "2Thess ", "1Tim ", "2Tim ", "Phil ", "Heb ", "James ", "1Pet ", "2Pet ", "1John ", "2John ", "3John ", "Jude ", "Rev "]

with open('test.txt') as f_in:
    with open('out.txt', 'w') as f_out:
        books = "|".join(ch_refs)
        for match in re.findall(rf'\[\[({books})(\d+):(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?(?:\+(\d+))?]]', f_in.read()):
            print(match)  # just printing this to show on screen what's happening
            b, c, v1, v2, ve = match
            for v in range(int(v1), int(v2)+1 if v2 else int(v1)+1):
                f_out.write(f'[[{b} {c}:{v}]]\n')
            if ve:
                f_out.write(f'[[{b} {c}:{ve}]]\n')
```

Writes the file as specified and shows on screen:

```
('Gen ', '1', '1', '5', '')
('Mark ', '5', '6', '13', '16')
```

Note that this doesn't deal with additional possible formats, like you asked about in the comments. I don't think "indefinitely long" is what you'd be going for here, but you might give a few grammar rules, like:

- The format is always `Book Chapter:Verses`
- `Book` is one from a select set of capitalised words
- `Chapter` is a positive integer
- `Verses` is `Range`, which may be followed by any number of additional `+Range`
- `Range` is either `Verse` or `Verse-Verse`
- `Verse` is a positive integer
- (space), `-` and `+` are symbols

That set of rules covers all the examples you gave, but also `Mark 5:2-4+10+11-14`, for example.

There's many ways to parse something like that out of a text, but regular expressions cannot do all the work in one go anymore. They can still match the part of the string that has all the verses, and by then we'll know for sure it's correctly structured - so we can use `.split` to loop over the parts:

```
import re

ch_refs = ["Gen ", "Exod ", "Lev ", "Num ", "Deut ", "Josh ", "Judg ", "Ruth ", "1Sam ", "2Sam ", "1Kings ", "2Kings ", "1Chron ", "2Chron ", "Ezr ", "Neh ", "Esth ", "Job ", "Ps ", "Prov ", "Eccless ", "Song ", "Isa ", "Jer ", "Lam ", "Ezek ", "Dan ", "Hos ", "Joel ", "Amos ", "Obad ", "Jonah ", "Micah ", "Nah ", "Hab ", "Zeph ", "Hag ", "Zech ", "Mal ", "Matt ", "Mark ", "Luke ", "John ", "Acts ", "Rom ", "1Cor ", "2Cor ", "Gal ", "Ephes ", "Phil ", "Col ", "1Thess ", "2Thess ", "1Tim ", "2Tim ", "Phil ", "Heb ", "James ", "1Pet ", "2Pet ", "1John ", "2John ", "3John ", "Jude ", "Rev "]

with open('test.txt') as f_in:
    with open('out.txt', 'w') as f_out:
        books = "|".join(ch_refs)
        for match in re.findall(rf'\[\[({books})(\d+):(\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:\+\d+(?:-\d+)?)*)]]', f_in.read()):
            print(match)  # just printing this to show on screen what's happening
            b, c, all_verses = match
            for verses in all_verses.split('+'):
                vs = verses.split('-')
                for v in range(int(vs[0]), int(vs[1])+1 if len(vs) > 1 else int(vs[0])+1):
                    f_out.write(f'[[{b} {c}:{v}]]\n')
```

Prints:

```
('Gen ', '1', '1-5')
('Mark ', '5', '6-13+16')
```

Have a look at https://regex101.com if you're wondering about those regular expressions. Just note that `{books}` is not part of it, it gets replaced with `Gen |Exod |Lev`  (etc., the value of `books`) so that it matches one of them for the first group. But literally writing it out in the regex makes it entirely unreadable.

Edit: note that the code above doesn't catch mistakes in the source text, like `[[Gen 1:10-8]]` (wrong order) or `[[Gen 1:1-100]]` (non-existent verse). It also doesn't account for something like `[[Gen 1:1-5, 2:2-4]]` - but from the solution above, you should be able to see that adding that is just more of the same.